# Why doesn't this table of images align on IE?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, html-table

I've been scratching my head for hours trying to get this banner (table of images) to align properly on IE (looks perfect in firefox and chrome). I'm not very good with HTML, can anyone help?

```
<table id="Table_01" width="750" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><a href="javascript:showToySkillHopup(); void(0);"> <img src="" width="221" height="100" alt="" ></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Colors+-and-+Shapes?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="114" height="51" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Eye-Hand+Coordination?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="144" height="51" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Language+-and-+Letters?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="133" height="51" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Movement?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="138" height="51" alt=""></img></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Numbers?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="114" height="49" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Problem+Solving?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="144" height="49" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Social+-and-+Emotional+Growth?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="133" height="49" alt=""></img></a></td>
        <td><a href="/buy/Skill+Level=Vision+-and-+Hearing?viewheader=N" target="_self"> <img src="" width="138" height="49" alt=""></img></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE:: link- -removed-
this banner looks perfect in Chrome/Firefox but not IE

UPDATE2:: sorry, that link you have to be a returned customer to site

UPDATE3:: screenshot uploaded:

[image]

[image]

I added all the `a` and `img` and it still does not align.

Comment: FIXED! added an extra quotation!!! stupid me.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some `</a>` closing tags.

Comment: The `<a>` tags aren't closed and neither are the `<img>` tags.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I added all the closing tags but it is still not fixed.